# Typescript type definition line too long - workaround?

Tags: typescript, syntax

How can I break this into either more lines or use some other method to create this type?

```
export type CountryCodeType = 'AD' | 'AE' | 'AF' | 'AG' | 'AI' | 'AL' | 'AM' | 'AO' | 'AQ' | 'AR' | 'AS' | 'AT' | 'AU' | 'AW' | 'AX' | 'AZ' | 'BA' | 'BB' | 'BD' | 'BE' | 'BF' | 'BG' | 'BH' | 'BI' | 'BJ' | 'BL' | 'BM' | 'BN' | 'BO' | 'BR' | 'BS' | 'BT' | 'BV' | 'BW' | 'BY' | 'BZ' | 'CA' | 'CC' | 'CD' | 'CF' | 'CG' | 'CH' | 'CI' | 'CK' | 'CL' | 'CM' | 'CN' | 'CO' | 'CR' | 'CU' | 'CV' | 'CW' | 'CX' | 'CY' | 'CZ' | 'DE' | 'DJ' | 'DK' | 'DM' | 'DO' | 'DZ' | 'EC' | 'EE' | 'EG' | 'EH' | 'ER' | 'ES' | 'ET' | 'FI' | 'FJ' | 'FK' | 'FM' | 'FO' | 'FR' | 'GA' | 'GB' | 'GD' | 'GE' | 'GF' | 'GG' | 'GH' | 'GI' | 'GL' | 'GM' | 'GN' | 'GP' | 'GQ' | 'GR' | 'GS' | 'GT' | 'GU' | 'GW' | 'GY' | 'HK' | 'HM' | 'HN' | 'HR' | 'HT' | 'HU' | 'ID' | 'IE' | 'IL' | 'IM' | 'IN' | 'IO' | 'IQ' | 'IR' | 'IS' | 'IT' | 'JE' | 'JM' | 'JO' | 'JP' | 'KE' | 'KG' | 'KH' | 'KI' | 'KM' | 'KN' | 'KP' | 'KR' | 'KW' | 'KY' | 'KZ' | 'LA' | 'LB' | 'LC' | 'LI' | 'LK' | 'LR' | 'LS' | 'LT' | 'LU' | 'LV' | 'LY' | 'MA' | 'MC' | 'MD' | 'ME' | 'MF' | 'MG' | 'MH' | 'MK' | 'ML' | 'MM' | 'MN' | 'MO' | 'MP' | 'MQ' | 'MR' | 'MS' | 'MT' | 'MU' | 'MV' | 'MW' | 'MX' | 'MY' | 'MZ' | 'NA' | 'NC' | 'NE' | 'NF' | 'NG' | 'NI' | 'NL' | 'NO' | 'NP' | 'NR' | 'NU' | 'NZ' | 'OM' | 'PA' | 'PE' | 'PF' | 'PG' | 'PH' | 'PK' | 'PL' | 'PM' | 'PN' | 'PR' | 'PS' | 'PT' | 'PW' | 'PY' | 'QA' | 'RE' | 'RO' | 'RS' | 'RU' | 'RW' | 'SA' | 'SB' | 'SC' | 'SD' | 'SE' | 'SG' | 'SH' | 'SI' | 'SJ' | 'SK' | 'SL' | 'SM' | 'SN' | 'SO' | 'SR' | 'SS' | 'ST' | 'SV' | 'SX' | 'SY' | 'SZ' | 'TC' | 'TD' | 'TF' | 'TG' | 'TH' | 'TJ' | 'TK' | 'TL' | 'TM' | 'TN' | 'TO' | 'TR' | 'TT' | 'TV' | 'TW' | 'TZ' | 'UA' | 'UG' | 'UK' | 'UM' | 'US' | 'UY' | 'UZ' | 'VA' | 'VC' | 'VE' | 'VG' | 'VI' | 'VN' | 'VU' | 'WF' | 'WS' | 'YE' | 'YT' | 'ZA' | 'ZM' | 'ZW'
```

Comment: Insert line breaks?

Comment: Line breaks seem like the most obvious solution. Also splitting the union into several smaller unions and then build up the union from the parts. It would be equivalent..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just insert line breaks wherever you feel it needs it.

```
export type CountryCodeType =
  | 'AD' | 'AE' | 'AF' | 'AG' | 'AI' | 'AL' | 'AM' | 'AO' | 'AQ' | 'AR' | 'AS'
  | 'AT' | 'AU' | 'AW' | 'AX' | 'AZ' | 'BA' | 'BB' | 'BD' | 'BE' | 'BF' | 'BG'
  | 'BH' | 'BI' | 'BJ' | 'BL' | 'BM' | 'BN' | 'BO' | 'BR' | 'BS' | 'BT' | 'BV'
  | 'BW' | 'BY' | 'BZ' | 'CA' | 'CC' | 'CD' | 'CF' | 'CG' | 'CH' | 'CI' | 'CK'
  | 'CL' | 'CM' | 'CN' | 'CO' | 'CR' | 'CU' | 'CV' | 'CW' | 'CX' | 'CY' | 'CZ'
  | 'DE' | 'DJ' | 'DK' | 'DM' | 'DO' | 'DZ' | 'EC' | 'EE' | 'EG' | 'EH' | 'ER'
  | 'ES' | 'ET' | 'FI' | 'FJ' | 'FK' | 'FM' | 'FO' | 'FR' | 'GA' | 'GB' | 'GD'
  | 'GE' | 'GF' | 'GG' | 'GH' | 'GI' | 'GL' | 'GM' | 'GN' | 'GP' | 'GQ' | 'GR'
  | 'GS' | 'GT' | 'GU' | 'GW' | 'GY' | 'HK' | 'HM' | 'HN' | 'HR' | 'HT' | 'HU'
  | 'ID' | 'IE' | 'IL' | 'IM' | 'IN' | 'IO' | 'IQ' | 'IR' | 'IS' | 'IT' | 'JE'
  | 'JM' | 'JO' | 'JP' | 'KE' | 'KG' | 'KH' | 'KI' | 'KM' | 'KN' | 'KP' | 'KR'
  | 'KW' | 'KY' | 'KZ' | 'LA' | 'LB' | 'LC' | 'LI' | 'LK' | 'LR' | 'LS' | 'LT'
  | 'LU' | 'LV' | 'LY' | 'MA' | 'MC' | 'MD' | 'ME' | 'MF' | 'MG' | 'MH' | 'MK'
  | 'ML' | 'MM' | 'MN' | 'MO' | 'MP' | 'MQ' | 'MR' | 'MS' | 'MT' | 'MU' | 'MV'
  | 'MW' | 'MX' | 'MY' | 'MZ' | 'NA' | 'NC' | 'NE' | 'NF' | 'NG' | 'NI' | 'NL'
  | 'NO' | 'NP' | 'NR' | 'NU' | 'NZ' | 'OM' | 'PA' | 'PE' | 'PF' | 'PG' | 'PH'
  | 'PK' | 'PL' | 'PM' | 'PN' | 'PR' | 'PS' | 'PT' | 'PW' | 'PY' | 'QA' | 'RE'
  | 'RO' | 'RS' | 'RU' | 'RW' | 'SA' | 'SB' | 'SC' | 'SD' | 'SE' | 'SG' | 'SH'
  | 'SI' | 'SJ' | 'SK' | 'SL' | 'SM' | 'SN' | 'SO' | 'SR' | 'SS' | 'ST' | 'SV'
  | 'SX' | 'SY' | 'SZ' | 'TC' | 'TD' | 'TF' | 'TG' | 'TH' | 'TJ' | 'TK' | 'TL'
  | 'TM' | 'TN' | 'TO' | 'TR' | 'TT' | 'TV' | 'TW' | 'TZ' | 'UA' | 'UG' | 'UK'
  | 'UM' | 'US' | 'UY' | 'UZ' | 'VA' | 'VC' | 'VE' | 'VG' | 'VI' | 'VN' | 'VU'
  | 'WF' | 'WS' | 'YE' | 'YT' | 'ZA' | 'ZM' | 'ZW'
```

For the curious, I'm much to lazy to do this by hand. I broke this up at roughly 80 characters using the find-replace function in VSCode with a regular expression:

[image: find-replace]

Comment: It seems the piece of information I was missing was that I needed to add a leading '|' to the list - without this, the first line break invalidates the list

Answer (score 2):

You can break it like this:

```
export type CountryCodeType =
        | 'AD'
        | 'AE'
        | 'AF';
```